# How to convert a query with inner join in sql to linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, linq

How to convert this SQL in c# code

```
   select t.Message
   from [dbo].[tblA] t
    inner join (
  select Message, max(CreatedDate) as MaxDate
   from [dbo].[tblA]
   group by Message
  ) tm on t.Message = tm.Message and t.CreatedDate = tm.MaxDate
 where  Type='Enter'
```

Can you help me please .

I just created this ..but with inner join in more complicated for me.

```
         var query = (from each in db.A
                              where each.StartDate == DateTime.Today
                              select each).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Your SQL doesn't have a join (it looks incomplete).  You don't need a join if you want the row with the max value.  Just use `OrderByDescending` and `First`.

Comment: The query won't even run.  How do you expect us to help you if you give non-working query???

Comment: var query = db.OrderByDescending( cv => cv.CreatedDate ).First();

Comment: var query = db.OrderByDescending( cv => cv.CreatedDate ).Select(x=> x.Type == 'Enter').First();

Comment: query is not valid, seems you are missing something

Comment: @juharr sorry i just edit my query

Comment: @Eric sorry the query was uncomplete :( , i just edit

Comment: @JordiJordi the query was incomplete , i just edit

Comment: @RezaRahmati sorry , i just edit the query

Comment: I agree @juharr comment, you want the Message with max date, you dont need inner join with the same table, you only need OrderByDescendig CreatedDate and take the first() which his take is 'Enter' , just like ive writted at: var query = db.OrderByDescending( cv => cv.CreatedDate ).Select(x=> x.Type == 'Enter').First(); if not , you could say what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: The `where` condition in your LINQ query does not match the one of your SQL query.

Comment: Also, your query makes no sense. You select the message column and then join by that column and the max creation date. You are not even using the creation date. You can just take your message with a select distinct. You can do that without a join and without involving the max creation date. You should really straighten out the problem and then ask a question that makes some actual sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `whole message record` in `tblA` with a `max CreatedDate` value, you can order the result and pick the first element, something like:

```
var query = from item in tblA
            where item.Type = "Enter"
            group item by item.Message into msgGroup
            select msgGroup.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want a message for which type is Enter and you want to get Max CreatedDate value for that message. If that's the requirement, i don't think you need inner join. You could use something like below in LINQ.

```
from m in tblA 
where m.Type = "Enter"
group m by m.Message into temp
select new 
{
 Message = temp.Message, 
 CreatedDate = ( from temp2 in temp select temp.CreatedDate).max()
}
```

Comment: thnx ,  i want to select all the message in this table , with a specific type and only that message which has max date of creation .